# Twig error saying "Expected tag name. Got something else instead"

Tags: php, twig, octobercms

I am using OctoberCMS and inside one of my layout files, I have put below code.

```
{% set i = 0 %}
                                    {% for photo in single_property.photos %}
                                        {% if i <= 3 %}

                                            {% if i == 0 %}
                                            First Photo : <br />
                                             <img src="{{photo.getPath() }}" height="30%" width="30%">
                                            {% else %} 
                                            Other Photo : <br />
                                            <img src="{{photo.getPath() }}" height="30%" width="30%">
                                            {% endif %} 
                                         <br />
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% set i = i + 1 %}
                                    {% endfor %}
```

The code is working fine, I am getting the expected result. But in code tab , I am keep getting this error saying,

> Expected tag name. Got something else instead.

[image]
Can someone suggest me what I am doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: That is just your editor trolling you man

Comment: If the code works, keep it. IDE's can be stupid sometimes.

Comment: That's strange .. Do we have any other twig method to be able to achieve same thing ? I want to show only 0 to 3 records and inside loop I want to check if I have first record if so put some condition.

Comment: The only other syntax that would go is `{% for photo in single_property.photos if i < 4 %}`

Comment: OK guys, I have come up with something new. I have mentioned in my answer which worked for me. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I have come up with something.

```
{% for key, photo in single_property.photos|slice(0, 4) %}                                       

                                            {% if key == 0 %}
                                            First Photo : <br />
                                             <img src="{{photo.getPath() }}" height="30%" width="30%">
                                            {% else %} 
                                            Other Photo : <br />
                                            <img src="{{photo.getPath() }}" height="30%" width="30%">
                                            {% endif %} 
                                         <br />


{% endfor %}
```

Here above I have used `key` and `slice` .

Used `key` to check my current index value of an array inside my loop and then I simply check with `key == 0` to check my first record inside my loop. And `slice` is used to get only 4 records out of the list.

Now the error disappeared as well and the code also works well.

Thanks for support.